Error: Generator "ts-node --transpile-only ./enum-generator" failed cannot find module './enum-generator'
I trying to install the schema from the prismadb to my local postgres db using command :
npx prisma db push --schema='calcom/packages/prisma/schema.prisma' but getting error
Also I have installed the ts-node was there anything else which needs to be installed?
Error: Generator "ts-node --transpile-only ./enum-generator" failed:

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module './enum-generator'
Require stack:
- /home/dev/calcom-docker/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:109:19)
    at requireResolveNonCached (/home/dev/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:549:16)
    at getProjectSearchDir (/home/dev/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:519:40)
    at phase3 (/home/dev/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:267:27)
    at bootstrap (/home/dev/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:47:30)
    at main (/home/dev/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:33:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dev/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:579:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/dev/calcom-docker/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript'
  ]
}


I ran into this error multiple times, when working on calcom exactly as you. Everytime I made changes to schema.prisma I would run npx prisma migrate dev and it would end up with this error.
To resolve this what worked was: just after when migration file is created, run a yarn dx which would generate prisma client without any errors.

Thanks used the same command yarn dx it resolved my error
